# A WebView service

Tags: android

I am trying to build an application which runs a service for checking through a list of websites stored in SQLite database and informs the user whenever any of the websites is down. Now since I have to use a WebView for this and since WebView cannot be opened in a service, I have managed to open an activity and make it invisible. The problem I am facing now is that I can't stop the activity which is starting the WebView activity. If I do the whole application stops working.

Answer (score 4):

This seems incredibly inefficient. If all you're looking for is 404s or some other indicator that the site is down, there's no need for a web view. Just call your URLs in a service (via a generic HTTP call) and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Dr. Dredel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59947/dr-dredel) answer, and I'll even take it one step further.  You probably shouldn't be doing that kind of heavy lifting on a mobile device.  Put your 404-checker on a web server (or use one that already exists) and use Android C2DM to send a notification down to the device when a site your are monitoring is offline.